# Correcting visualization of other functions inside the grid function

Tags: output-formatting, grid-layouts

I wish the <kbd>DateObject[{2019, 8, 27}]</kbd> function and <kbd>TimeObject[{2, 35}]</kbd> function could be visible on my grid.

```
data={{"CaixaPokémon",DateObject[{2019,8,27}],22.41,TimeObject[{2,35}]},{"second",11,5,6},{"third",111,8,9},{"fourth",1111,10,11}};
Text@Grid[Prepend[data,{"Projeto","Data","Metros","Tempo"}],Background->{None,{Lighter[Yellow,.9],{White,Lighter[Blend[{Blue,Green}],.8]}}},
Dividers->{{Darker[Gray,.6],{Lighter[Gray,.5]},Darker[Gray,.6]},{Darker[Gray,.6],Darker[Gray,.6],{False},Darker[Gray,.6]}},Alignment->{{Center,Center,{Center}}},ItemSize->{{10,3,5,5}},Frame->Darker[Gray,.6],ItemStyle->14,Spacings->{15,.8}]
```

[image]

Is there anything else I should do for better viewing?

Comment: The culprit is your choice of `ItemSize->{{10,3,5,5}}`, values here for 2nd and last columns are not enough. You may change this to `ItemSize -> {{10, Full, 5, Full}}` to prevent line-wrapping as the help page says. Or simply use `ItemSize->Full` so that every item is at its full width and height.

Answer (score 3):

You can also wrap the grid object with [`Style`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style.html) using the option [`LineBreakWithin -> False`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineBreakWithin.html):

```
Style[#, LineBreakWithin -> False] &@
 Grid[Prepend[data, {"Projeto", "Data", "Metros", "Tempo"}], 
  Background -> {None, {Lighter[Yellow, .9], {White, Lighter[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .8]}}}, 
  Dividers -> {{Darker[Gray, .6], {Lighter[Gray, .5]}, Darker[Gray, .6]}, 
     {Darker[Gray, .6], Darker[Gray, .6], {False},  Darker[Gray, .6]}},
  Alignment -> {{Center, Center, {Center}}}, 
  Frame -> Darker[Gray, .6], ItemStyle -> 14, Spacings -> {15, .8}]
```

[image]

With `Spacings -> {1, .8}` we get:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As recommended by our contributor [Alx](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/35574/alx):

```
data = {{"CaixaPokémon", DateObject[{2019, 8, 27}], 22.41, 
    TimeObject[{2, 35}]}, {"second", 11, 5, 6}, {"third", 111, 8, 
    9}, {"fourth", 1111, 10, 11}};
Text@Grid[Prepend[data, {"Projeto", "Data", "Metros", "Tempo"}], 
  Background -> {None, {Lighter[Yellow, .9], {White, 
      Lighter[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .8]}}}, 
  Dividers -> {{Darker[Gray, .6], {Lighter[Gray, .5]}, 
     Darker[Gray, .6]}, {Darker[Gray, .6], Darker[Gray, .6], {False}, 
     Darker[Gray, .6]}}, Alignment -> {{Center, Center, {Center}}}, 
  ItemSize -> {{10, Full, 5, Full}}, Frame -> Darker[Gray, .6], 
  ItemStyle -> 14, Spacings -> {15, .8}]
```

[image]